# Can't getResourcesAsStream() from a folder (in a jar)

Tags: java, jar, stream, resources

I have a problem, I want to list the files in "default" folder, this folder is in the resources folder :

-resources/languages/default/manyfiles

The second line throws a nullPointerException

```
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("languages/default/");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

It seems I can't do this with a folder but only with a file. The problem is I can't use File because this is inside a jar.

EDIT : here the content of the jar : 
http://www.mediafire.com/view/05u5w20xupt1mo1/javapbfolder.bmp

Comment: Is the path correct? If you have a `URLClassLoader` instance, which you normally would, then `getResourceAsStream` should return a the items in the folder.

Comment: You're trying to ask for a *directory* as a stream... that makes no sense, regardless of whether it's in a jar file or in the filesystem.

Comment: @JonSkeet actually the NIO.2 API provides a DirectoryStream as well as a java.util.stream.Stream for directories, AFAIK. Both are different from java.io stream, though, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Puce: Exactly - there's no sense in which an `InputStream` will work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way to list the contents of a folder. The reason is that there concept of a file system behind the class resource loading, just names/location of a resource.

It depends what you want to do, how to work around this. Possible solutions come to my mind:

1. Retrieve the URL from one resource in the directory. Extract the JAR file from the URL and open the JAR via the ZipFile class. This is "hacky" and may or may not work, depending on the platform you run and security settings.
2. Generate an index file when you pack the JAR that contains the list of the resources.
3. Put in a JAR into the resource, that you then open via ZipFile.

Comment: I think i'll try the 2nd solution, it seem to be the cleanest way.

Comment: When you say "Generate an index file when you pack the JAR", is there a way to do it automatically ?

Comment: Note: using the NIO.2 File API and the zip filesystem provider, reading jars and even listing contents of dirs inside jars became much simpler than manually working with ZipFile.

Comment: Even with nio directory stream I can't list the content of a folder